# How to use FastZip compressing files and folders together?

Tags: c#, sharpziplib, fastzip

I try to use file filter and directory filter to choose specified files and folders , but the files in sub folder are affected by file filter .

Example :

file filter : `@"//1.txt$;2.txt$"`

directory filter : `@"//sub$"`

Only `1.txt` & `2.txt` were compressed in `sub` folder , and i want all the files in `sub` folder compressed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that fastzip means the one class of SharpZipLib.
According to the documentation https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FastZip the parameter for fileFilter is optional. If null is passed, all files in the specified folder should be compressed

Comment: Thank you for your answer . The 1.txt & 2.txt are in the same parent folder of "sub" folder , and i want theses files to be compressed but not the files in "sub" folder.

Comment: So you want to exclude the "sub" folder?